# In Ionic1 and Angularfire, how do I retrieve a sub array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have gotten my code to read a list and then push the $id as the stateParam to the next screen. However I cant seem to read a sub array correctly even if I set the reference statically to that. For example, here is my structure in Firebase:

```
  "Providers" : {
"2" : {
  "-KrMKUqGM-3dEYLPsgUB" : {
    "business_name" : "Coca Cola",
    "first_name" : "Dave",
    "last_name" : "Watson"
  },
  "234543fdgst3EYLPqGM-d" : {
    "business_name" : "Pepsi",
    "first_name" : "Joe",
    "last_name" : "Styles"
  }
},
 "3" : {
  "-KrMKUqGM-3dEYLPsgUB" : {
    "business_name" : "Nestle",
    "first_name" : "Sarah",
    "last_name" : "Douglas"
  },
  "234543fdgst3EYLPqGM-d" : {
    "business_name" : "Cadburys",
    "first_name" : "Michael",
    "last_name" : "Smith"
  }
}
}
```

I have a service that allows the user to pick the type which has ids of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc. Once they have selected that, they need to select a provider as seen in the firebase example above.

This is where I have the problem. I cant seem to get that sub array. IE.

```
  "-KrMKUqGM-3dEYLPsgUB" : {
    "business_name" : "Coca Cola",
    "first_name" : "Dave",
    "last_name" : "Watson"
  },
  "234543fdgst3EYLPqGM-d" : {
    "business_name" : "Pepsi",
    "first_name" : "Joe",
    "last_name" : "Styles"
  }
```

To read as an array. Here is my code so far:

```
angular.module('buddyproviders', ['firebase'])

.service('BuddyProviders', ['$firebaseArray', 
function($firebaseArray){
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/Providers/2/');
var items = $firebaseArray(ref);
var providers = {
    'providers': items  
}
return providers;    
}]);
```

Can anyone give advice on how to fix the service to read correctly? I am also using AngularFire

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

```
 entriesRef$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
 this.entriesRef$ = database.list('/Providers/' + providerNumber);
 this.entriesRef$.subscribe(snapshots => { yourmapping here });
```